# Water spraying from tailpipe?

Tags: honda, exhaust

i have a 2010 honda fit. the other day i was on my lunch break sitting in my car with it running. which i do all the time. about 30 minutes later i hear some sound from the back of my car and i see water spraying from the tail pipe. it sounded like my car was trying to accelerate but my car was in park. i don’t think it was coolant. people are saying head gasket and to check my oil but my oil is fine?

Comment: Check for loss of coolant. If none, this may be water as a byproduct of combustion. Exaggerating water from exhaust can be from higher than normal humidity and cooler outside temps while idling. In general, the exhaust system heats up while driving to turn normal water from combustion, into steam. Humidity, moisture, isn't combustible and leaves a high temperature vapor into the exhaust system. Idling on a cool, humid day may not heat up the exhaust system, resulting in water pooling inside until it blocks exhaust flow. Driving usually boils and blows out condensation.